# getting 500 intenal error when setting 301 redirect using .htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, http-code-500

I am trying to use a 301 redirect to direct users and bots to my new site but when I put the `.htaccess` live I keep getting a 500 internal error shown.

The site is actually a subdomain which i want to redirect to another subdomain on another site. I'm not sure if that's relevant but I thought I should include this information.

The web server I'm using is Apache and this is the htaccess code I'm using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.blog.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any idea what might be wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

Not guaranteed this is it, but try removing a line at a time until the error stops. That'll help you see which particular bit is causing the problem.
Getting a 500 from htaccess is sometimes a sign you're trying to do something you're not allowed to. Is mod_rewrite actually enabled, for example? The same for the Options line; If the server isn't configured with `AllowOverride Options` then it might be the FollowSymLinks line.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why it wasnt working but got in contact with the host and this is the solution they provided.. put it in the httpdocs folder, works fine

```
Redirect 301 / http://blog.example.co.uk
```

Comment: `Redirect` is in mod_alias, whereas `RewriteRule` is in mod_rewrite, so maybe mod_rewrite wasn't enabled - as Su' suggested? But you are also redirecting to a different URL than in your rewrite example above.